# Header module slideshow on main page

Tags: header, opencart

Opencart 1.5.3.1
How to add a module to the slideshow in the header?  only need to display it on the main page.
How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the code you want to show only on the main page with:

```
if (!isset($this->request->get['route']) || $this->request->get['route'] == 'common/home') {

   //code here

}
```